# UI.Component Issue in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

I am using **latest version of Meteor is 0.83 and iron-router is 0.82**.I got one error as shown below the code:

```
 if (!UI.Component.get('itemImage'))
          helpers();
```

**Error :** Undefined UI.Component

I am new to meteor.So i didn't get any idea about this.Please suggest me how to do?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing as `UI.Component` anymore. It got replaced by `Blaze.View`, but the API is a little different, so you need to be extremely careful and try to resist the temptation to simply replace all the occurrences of `UI.Component` with `Blaze.View`.